# How to cache Scaffold's drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to cache `scaffold`'s drawer so it would not call drawer's build method everytime the drawer open:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerDemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawerDemoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DrawerDemoPage> createState() => _DrawerDemoPageState();
}

class _DrawerDemoPageState extends State<DrawerDemoPage> {
  final _drawer = const _MyDrawer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Drawer')),
      drawer: _drawer,
    );
  }
}

class _MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MyDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_MyDrawer> createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<_MyDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('call build');
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 60),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

However, drawer's build method is called everytime when drawer open even though I made drawer an instance variable of this page.

Then I add `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and set `wantKeepAlive` for `true` expect it would work like `TabBarView`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerDemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawerDemoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DrawerDemoPage> createState() => _DrawerDemoPageState();
}

class _DrawerDemoPageState extends State<DrawerDemoPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  final _drawer = const _MyDrawer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Drawer')),
      drawer: _drawer,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class _MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MyDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_MyDrawer> createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<_MyDrawer>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print('call build');
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 60),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Also, drawer's build called everytime when opened.

**Any idea make the build method called only once?**

Comment: Build will be called every-time there is change in screen but your const widget won't be updated so you can use them.